# C# Erro NullReferenceException em método ToList()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou trabalhando num projeto em C# MVC para WEB com o EntityFramework. Consegui configurá-lo junto ao banco de dados e também instalei o Ninject.

O primeiro controller que estou trabalhando é a de Usuários. Quero criar um ambiente para manutenção desses dados, como consultar, adicionar, remover e etc. Então eu criei as classes, controllers, views e etc. Por enquanto o banco de dados está vazio.

Ocorre que estou com um problema justamente na listagem. Ao tentar chamar a View "Index" do "UsuarioController", ele gera o erro abaixo no método de listagem "Lista()" em "UsuariosDAO"

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   Aplicacoes.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma
>   instância de um objeto.

Eis o código:

**`UsuarioController`**

```
private UsuarioDAO uDao;

public UsuarioController(UsuarioDAO uDao)
{
    this.uDao = uDao;
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IList<Usuarios> usuarios = uDao.Lista();
    return View(usuarios);
}
```

**`UsuariosDAO`**

```
private AplicacoesContexto contexto;
public void UsuariosDAO(AplicacoesContexto contexto)
{
 this.contexto = contexto;
}

public IList<Usuarios> Lista()
{    
    return contexto.usuarios.ToList(); //o erro é aqui    
}
```

**`Index.cshtml de UsuarioController`**

```
@model IList<Aplicacoes.Entidades.Usuarios>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Usuários";
}
<h4>Lista de Usuários</h4>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Matricula</th>
            <th>DV</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Cargo</th>
            <th>Função</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var usuario in @Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@usuario.Id</td>
                <td>@usuario.Matricula</td>
                <td>@usuario.MatriculaDV</td>
                <td>@usuario.Nome</td>
                <td>@usuario.Cargo.Cargo</td>
                <td>@usuario.Funcao.Funcao</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**`Usuarios.cs`** - Model

```
public class Usuarios
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(60)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    //Outras propriedades
}
```

O que encontrei na internet me descreve que o método `ToList()` não aceita valor nulo e que a solução deveria instanciá-lo antes. Fiz o código abaixo e não funcionou comigo:

```
IList<Usuarios> lista = new List<Usuarios>;
lista = this.contexto.usuarios.ToList(); //o erro é aqui
return lista;
```

Comment: Você tem um `NullReferenceException` naquela linha porque ou o campo `contexto` é nulo, ou o campo `usuarios` do campo `contexto` é nulo. Verifique como o objeto `UsuariosDAO` está sendo criado, e como o parâmetro `AplicacoesContexto` que é passado para ele é criado, e veja se algum deles é nulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que a variável `uDao` não está sendo inicializada em momento algum, pelo menos não no código que foi postado na pergunta. Veja este trecho

```
private UsuarioDAO uDao;

public UsuarioController(UsuarioDAO uDao)
{
    this.uDao = uDao;
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IList<Usuarios> usuarios = uDao.Lista(); //NullReferenceException - uDao é nulo
}
```

**Se** esta variável estiver sendo inicializada fora deste código - ao chamar o construtor de **`UsuarioController`**. Aí problema é que a variável `contexto` não está sendo inicializada. Veja esse trecho do código:

```
private AplicacoesContexto contexto;
public void UsuariosDAO(AplicacoesContexto contexto)
{
   this.contexto = contexto;
}

public IList<Usuarios> Lista()
{
    return contexto.usuarios.ToList(); 
    //contexto pode estar nulo, certifique-se de ter inicializado a variável
}
```

Aliás, o método `UsuariosDAO(AplicacoesContexto contexto)` (o qual eu imagino que seja o construtor dessa classe) não deveria ter `void` na assinatura, isso deveria gerar um erro de compilação.

**Outro ponto importante**

> O que encontrei na internet me descreve que o método `ToList()` não aceita valor nulo e que a solução deveria instanciá-lo antes. Fiz o código abaixo e não funcionou comigo:

```
IList<Usuarios> lista = new List<Usuarios>;
lista = this.contexto.usuarios.ToList();
```

Isso não está bem certo. Veja bem: `o método ToList() não aceita valor nulo`, o que acontece é que você não pode chamar o `ToList()` (e **nenhum** outro método) em variáveis que sejam nulas. Veja o exemplo:

```
string[] array = null;
List<string> list = array.ToList(); //NullReferenceException -> array é null    
var query = array.Where(x => x == "umaString"); //NullReferenceException  -> array é null
```

O código também não faz sentido. O `ToList()` está sendo aplicado em `contexto.usuarios` e não na variável `lista`.

---

<sub>As informações passadas são o suficiente para resolver o seu problema, porém me avise se achar que falta alguma coisa que eu edito a resposta com mais detalhes.</sub>

Comment: Obrigado jbueno! Você me ajudou muito! Consegui resolver o erro. Realmente retirando o void do método que iniciava a variavel contexto em UsuariosDAO foi a solução! E obrigado pelas dicas também!